# Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-all.zip'

Tags: eclipse, gradle, windows-10, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to manually update a minecraft mod/update a deprecated mod, and I have changed the build.gradle to match the Forge version I need, and it had an original error that I resolved which was it was using an outdated gradle build I think. The original error is this

```
 Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-all.zip'.
```

But I resolved that by changing the gradle wrapper properties to the version of gradle the forge version MDK has, but now it is giving me this new error. I have no idea how to fix this error and am looking for help.

Comment: Could you provide the new error?